# MapBasic freezes everytime i use "."

Tags: mapbasic

I'm using Map Basic IDE Version 1.6.0.0. Every time I use the "." key the IDE always freezes. This freeze happens anytime I use this key, whether it be for comments, or to access a  variable's fields. Does anyone know how to fix this?
I'm assuming that using this key triggers some sort of auto-save or something but I am unsure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the comments at the very bottom of the developer's page here.
It is a bug that causes a 'hang' for a few seconds.
https://mustafaozcetin.wordpress.com/mapbasic/mapbasicide-en/

Comment: Cool thanks! I've bypassed the hang by simply copying and pasting the "." whenever I need it. Although now I have developed a fear of pressing the key when programming in other languages XD